# Looking for a wireless router with a USB-port that can share a connected flash drive's files so they can be viewed with a browser using http, no ftp

Tags: router

So, I'm looking for a wireless router that can share the files of a connected USB-drive so they can be viewed by any PC connected to the router with only the use of a browser and http.

The router would be needed to make the files available for viewing with a browser at http://routerIP:portnumber, since the OS of the connected PCs is very limited and can't use ftp or connect to devices on the network.

If anyone happens to know such a router (if it happens to exist), or alternatively a router that works well with custom firmware, please do share your wisdom with someone who's a complete rookie at all this stuff.